In flutter and dart, how to query a blob column?
the sqlite database table is created as:
        CREATE TABLE Books (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, path TEXT, hash blob);
        CREATE UNIQUE INDEX path_uni ON Books(path);
        CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hash_uni ON Books(hash);

and after insert some data into the database, I tried querying the "hash" column as below:
final int id = 1;
database?.query('Books', where: 'id= ?', whereArgs: [id]).then(
        (rows) {

      if (rows.isEmpty) {
          // do something...
     
      } else {
        final hash = rows.first['hash'] as Uint8List;
        print('hash: $hash'); // the printed hash is correct, 16 bytes array
        
        // use the "hash" from query result as a known existed value to do the next query:
        database?.query('Books', where: 'hash = ?', whereArgs: [hash]).then(
            (rows) {
              print('query hash: $rows'); // here print a empty list "[]"
        });
      }
    });

I can ensure all the table names and column names are correct without spelling error.
So, why is the hash-query result is empty?
I have tried use hexHash to query the database, and still get nothing back.
final String hashToCheckHex = hash.map((byte) => byte.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join('');
database?.query('Books', where: 'hex(hash) = ?', whereArgs: [hashToCheckHex]).then(
            (rows) {
              print('query hash: $rows'); // still get nothing.
        });


1- Make sure you have a database set up (SQLite example below):
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

// Open the database
Database db = await openDatabase('my_database.db');

2- Query the database and retrieve the blob column data as Uint8List:
List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = await db.rawQuery('SELECT my_blob_column FROM my_table');

if (results.isNotEmpty)
{
Uint8List blobData = results[0]['my_blob_column'];
  // Use the blobData as needed
}

3- Ensure you handle the blob data appropriately based on your application's requirements.
Remember to adjust the database access code according to your specific database setup and package usage.

This kind of answers the title of the question but completely ignores the body. They are already able to pull the blob column but are not able to run a query matching against that pulled data.
